# QuickFix rejecting messages with error "Out of order repeating group members"

Tags: quickfix, fix-protocol

We are using QuickFix to extract trades and orders from ICE exchange. The current .NET application which is fetching the security definition requests is running quite fine. Our task is to migrate the application to Scala. While submitting the security definition request QuickFIx is rejecting the messages with "**Out of order repeating group members**" error .

```
Request : 8=FIX.4.2_9=51_35=c_48=0_167=FUT_320=XXX_Security_Request 0_321=3_10=175

QuickFix is rejecting with message : 8=FIX.4.2_9=132_35=3_34=12_49=xxxx_50=xxxxxx_52=20200805-10:49:01.193_56=ICE_45=12_58=Out of order repeating group members, field=305_371=305_372=d_10=097_

Session config settings: 
[DEFAULT]
ConnectionType=initiator
StartTime=00:00:00
EndTime=23:59:59
FileLogPath=log
FileStorePath=store
SocketConnectPort=*****
SocketConnectHost=*****
ResetOnLogon=Y
ResetOnDisconnect=Y
AllowUnknownMsgFields=Y
ReconnectInterval=8
ValidateIncomingMessages=N
FileLogPath=.\Log\FixLog
FileLogBackupPath=.\Log\Backup

[SESSION]
BeginString=FIX.4.2
SenderCompID=****
TargetCompID=ICE
HeartBtInt=30
SenderSubID=******
UseDataDictionary=Y
DataDictionary=.\Config\FIX42.xml
ReconnectInterval=8
ValidateUserDefinedFields=N
AllowUnknownMsgFields=Y
ValidateFieldsOutOfOrder=N
```

We are using same FIX dictionary(FIX42.xml) as the currently running .NET application so not sure how the this is happening. Could someone please help us in resolving this ?

Comment: It sounds like your scala app (there's a scala FIX engine?) is sending a malformed message.  Did you try manually decoding the message above against your DD?

Comment: http://quickfix-j.364392.n2.nabble.com/Out-of-order-repeating-group-members-td5416062.html

Comment: ValidateUnorderedGroupFields =N